# how to store an integer value in to sql table

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

i created this table and i want to be able to add Integer value of 99 in to Assgn_Id and Ben_Id. so i am very confident with my create table query.

```
Create table Advisor (
         Advisor# Integer,
         AdvisorName Varchar2(15),
         Assgn_Id Integer,
         Ben_Id Integer);
```

my second query is where i get confused. after i inserted the values into the table it seems like it work fine, but when i describe the table i see Number(38) datatype into both columns instead of Integers(99).

```
Insert Into Advisor (Assgn_Id, Ben_Id)
        Values(99, 99);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `insert into Advisor (Assgn_Id, Ben_Id) Values (99, 99)` inserts two integer values, and you can see them by using `select Assgn_Id, Ben_Id from Advisor`. There's no `Number(38)` as a result of that `select` statement.

Comment: what i mean is that values(99, 99) are not inserted into the table as INTEGERS. Instead they are stored as NUMERIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer, INT, smallint are ansi defined data types - that Oracle has implemented as a number

I like to use integer for my tables because I'm lazy, it's easier to type.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i54335)..

> SQL statements that create tables and clusters can also use ANSI data
>   types and data types from the IBM products SQL/DS and DB2. Oracle
>   recognizes the ANSI or IBM data type name that differs from the Oracle
>   Database data type name. It converts the data type to the equivalent
>   Oracle data type, records the Oracle data type as the name of the
>   column data type, and stores the column data in the Oracle data type
>   based on the conversions shown in the tables that follow.